# Bad performance on PASCAL VOC2007 data when use Bags-of-features approach

Tags: classification, vision, feature-selection

I used basic components in the bags of features framework:
SIFT + Kmeans + VQ + SVM
I got an average ap of only ~15%, some literatures using similar basic components claim to have average ap of ~45% and achive up to 75% after using additional encoding plus spatial pooling...why is that?

Thanks guys!